# In Python what does putting a variable or command next to a empty () do?

Tags: python

For example print() or a random variable like draw(). Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: that's a function. It performs a task

Comment: It calls that function with no arguments.

Comment: The terminology your looking for is _function call_. The left-hand name, such as `print`, must be a function object (or implement the `__call__` 'magic method'). The the pare of parenthesis on the right is called the _call operator_. This is a very basic programming concept. Google the term _"Python functions"_.

Comment: `()` is the call operator. If the object is a callable (e.g. a function), it *calls* it.

Comment: You should really take a programming book or tutorial. I'm not saying this to be mean, but you should really do, your learning method is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It calls that function with no arguments. – (Oliver Charlesworth)

Comment: jsbueno.stealanswerfrom(Oliver Charlesworth)

Comment: thanks heavens they've setup this "community wiki" thingy for these occasions.